Derivative of $x^x$: why wrong answer?
I know by taking log on both sides, one can derive the derivative of $x^x$, which is $x^x \left(\ln x+1\right)$. I tried another method but got the wrong answer. I regarded the base $x$ as another variable $y$, and applies chain rule, which gives $$\frac{d\left(x^x\right)}{dx}=\frac{dy^x}{dy}\frac{dy}{dx}=y^x \ln y\cdot1=x\ln x$$What is my mistake?

Recall the derivative of $f(x)$ can be roughly regarded as the change of $f$ when $x$ increases by a little. In your argument, you only consider the effect of the change of $x$ on the base part, but not the power part, so your answer is not the derivative of $x^x$.

Chain rule requires function composition $f(g(x))$. What would be your $f$ and $g$ in this case?

The derivative is not $x^x \ln (x+1)$. It's $x^x (\ln(x) +1)$.

This question is similar to: Why can't I take the derivative of $x^x$ as $x(x^{x-1})$?. Although the misconception is different, the answers there show how to apply the chain rule correctly.

Let's recall the equation $x^x = \exp(x\ln(x))$ and then apply the chain rule to it.

In the chain rule, both functions in the composition must depend only one variable. Otherwise, it does not work.
In what you are trying to do is to you have one function $y(x) = x$, and another $f(x, y) = y^x$. Note that the second function depends on two variables.
Later in multivariate calculus you will learn a more complicated chain rule (total derivative formula) to deal with this situation — this will require you to take separately the derivative with respect to $x$ and with respect to $y$ (these are called partial derivatives and denoted using $\partial$). Here it is:
$$\begin{align}\frac{\mathrm{d}f}{\mathrm{d}x}(x,x) &= \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(x,x)\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x}(x) + \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x,x)&:&f(x,y)=y^x, y(x)=x \\[1ex]&=\left.\dfrac{\partial y^x}{\partial y}\dfrac{\mathrm d x}{\mathrm d x}+\dfrac{\partial y^x}{\partial x}\quad\right\vert_{y:=x} \\[1ex]&= \left.(y^x \ln y)\cdot 1 + xy^{x-1}~\right\vert_{y:=x} \\[1ex]&= \left.y^x(\ln y + xy^{-1})~\right\vert_{y:=x} \\[1ex]&= x^x(\ln x + 1)\end{align}$$
